# Testing functions written in aarch64 asm

Tags: assembly

I had a few functions that were written in C which I had to rewrite in assembly for aarch64. How do I go about setting unit tests for the functions. And what environment would I require to do the same. I have a rasberry pi and linux pc with me, would I be able to compile and run the aarch code on them

```
#include "c_function.c"
#include "asm_function.asm"
void main() 
{
 int c_ans=c_add(4, 5);
 int asm_ans=asm_add(4, 5);
 if(c_ans! = asm_ans) 
   printf("Wrong Ans\n") ;
}
```

What environment would I need to compile and test this?